# Install adaptive theme for Moodle via admin account

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

The platform used moodle.org. The website runs on actual website.

The point how to install theme on local development first? I currently have loaded data on local website  e.g localhost/moodle and it shows first page with courses. However to install theme need to have administrator user but how to create and access on website? Also if have account this helps to test theme a full website locally

I installed moodle and it allowed me to create user but if I create that user I cannot connect data to website via mariadb from sql file which have courses, forum, posts and other moodle details.

I aiming to install https://moodle.org/plugins/theme_adaptable 4.1 version

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line to install plugins

First download and unzip the theme to the theme directory

eg `theme/adaptable/`

Then use `php admin/cli/upgrade.php` to install it

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Administration_via_command_line#Upgrading